# How to filter ionCards using ionSearchbar in react?

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, searchbar, ionic5, ionic-react

I'm using ionic-framework with react. I want to use ion-searchbar component to filter the cards based on their title. I have used, but stuck in how to add functionality to this searchbar component in react. Please tell me how do I filter ion-cards with ionSearchabar in react. The code that I've written is below:

```
import {IonCardSubtitle,IonCardContent, IonIcon, IonCardTitle, IonCard, 
IonCol, IonRow,  IonBackButton, IonContent, IonHeader, IonPage, 
IonTitle, IonToolbar, IonLabel,IonSearchbar,IonFooter,} from'@ionic/react';

 import {
    chevronForwardOutline,
     arrowForwardOutline, 
     homeOutline
    } from 'ionicons/icons';

 import React, { useState }  from 'react';
 import usa from '../assets/writing-screen-icons/img.svg';
const countries =[
    {
      id:1,
      title: "usa",
      subtitle: "country",
      route: "/country/usa",
      thumbnail: usa      
    },
    {
      id:2,
      title: "pakistan",
      subtitle: "country",
      route: "/country/pk",
      thumbnail: usa        
    },
    {
      id:3,
      title: "france",
      subtitle: "country",
      route: "/country/france",
      thumbnail: usa  
      
    },
      id:4,
      title: "canada",
      subtitle: "country",
      route: "/country/canada",
      thumbnail: usa  
      
    },
      id:5,
      title: "uk",
      subtitle: "country",
      route: "/country/uk",
      thumbnail: usa  
       }
  ];


const Country React.FC = () => {
const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');

const showCardCols=(topic:any, index:any)=>{
    return(
    <IonCol size="12" key="index">
    <IonCard mode="ios" routerLink={topic.route}> 
    <img src={topic.thumbnail}></img>
    <IonCardSubtitle>{topic.subtitle}</IonCardSubtitle>
    <IonCardTitle>{topic.title}</IonCardTitle>
    <IonIcon icon={chevronForwardOutline} />
    </IonCard>
    </IonCol>
    );
  }
return (
  <IonPage>
  <IonContent fullscreen>
 
  <h1>Countries</h1>

  
  <IonSearchbar mode="ios" value={searchText} onIonChange={e => setSearchText(e.detail.value!)}></IonSearchbar>
  <IonGrid>

  <IonRow>
 {writingTopics.map(showCardCols)}
  </IonRow>
  </IonGrid>
  
  </IonContent>
  </IonPage>
  
  );
  };
  
  
  
  export default Country;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some filter logic to your `showCardCols` function. Actually your function maps the array and returns it without making any operation.

For example, you could call a function from your `render` :

```
<IonRow>
 {showCardCols()}
</IonRow>
```

And then, from your function, choose which card to display :

```
const showCardCols = () => {
    return(
      countries.forEach((element, index) => { // <-- Iterate over your array
        if(element.title.indexOf(searchText) !== -1){ // <-- Check if title of the country matches your search text
          <IonCol size="12" key="index">
           <IonCard mode="ios" routerLink={element.route}> 
            <img src={element.thumbnail}></img>
            <IonCardSubtitle>{element.subtitle}</IonCardSubtitle>
            <IonCardTitle>{element.title}</IonCardTitle>
            <IonIcon icon={chevronForwardOutline} />
           </IonCard>
          </IonCol>
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I solved using the filter() method.